# golua - declaring lua class with defined methods

Tags: go, lua

I'm trying to use [golua package](https://github.com/aarzilli/golua) to build an extension API for my application written in Go. My idea is to have several classes exposed to lua VM, for example `Book` class:

```lua
local book = Book.Create("Le Petit Prince")
print(book)
book:save()
```

What I'm able to do now is just basic:

```
type Book struct {
    Id int64
    Title string
}

func BookCreate(L *lua.State) int {
    title := L.ToString(1)
    p := &Book{Id: 1, Title: title}
    L.PushGoStruct(p)
    return 1
}

func BookToString(L *lua.State) int {
    book, _ := L.ToGoStruct(1).(*Book)
    L.PushString(fmt.Sprintf("Book(Id=%d, Title=\"%s\")", book.Id, book.Title))
    return 1
}

L := lua.NewState()
defer L.Close()
L.OpenLibs()

L.NewMetaTable("Book")
L.SetMetaMethod("Create", BookCreate)
L.SetMetaMethod("tostring", BookToString)
L.SetGlobal("Book")
```

Which allows me to do this:

```lua
local book = Book.Create("Le Petit Prince")
print(Book.tostring(book))
```

But not this:

```
local book = Book.Create("Le Petit Prince")
print(book:tostring())

// reflect: call of reflect.Value.Type on zero Value
```

#### My questions

1. How to create lua class equivalent to one described in [A Simplified Way to Declare Lua Classes](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleLuaClasses)?
2. How to add "magic methods" to class like `__tostring` [here](http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=u107/meta2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used go, but it looks like you never set `Book` as a metatable for the new book you create. Im *fairly sure* this does not happen automatically.

See an example I found here https://github.com/stevedonovan/luar/blob/master/luar.go#L52

What is important here is that when a userdata or any object is made (your book), you need to get the global metatable and then set it as metatable with `L.SetMetaTable(-2)`

Comment: You are right! It took me some time but I think I've figured this out finally. I'll wrap up and post my solution later for future generations... Thank you @rochet2

Answer (score 0):

After [@Rochet2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3586583/rochet2)'s answer and after reading [Chapter 28. User-Defined Types in C](http://www.lua.org/pil/28.html) of [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html) I've came up with working solution. I know nothing about Lua and just a little about Go so I might be wrong in my conclusions.

> This edition of *Programming in Lua* was written for Lua 5.0 - [golua](https://github.com/aarzilli/golua) utilizes Lua 5.1 (for now).

---

#### `BookCreate` function

We create new *userdata* instead of pushing plain Go *struct* to stack. Then we set *metatable* of newly created `book` to "Book".

`L.NewUserdata` returns `unsafe.Pointer` so we cast it to `Book`.

```golang
func BookCreate(L *lua.State) int {
    title := L.ToString(1)
    book := (*Book)(L.NewUserdata(uintptr(unsafe.Sizeof(Book{}))))

    L.LGetMetaTable("Book")
    L.SetMetaTable(-2)

    book.Id = 1;
    book.Title = title;

    return 1
}
```

---

#### `BookToString` function

Here we just take *userdata* from stack and cast it to `Book`.

> Be aware that what we pop out of stack might not be pointer to `Book` struct so if we want to prevent nil pointers / other Go errors some basic type check might be required.

```
func BookToString(L *lua.State) int {
    book := (*Book)(L.ToUserdata(1))
    L.PushString(fmt.Sprintf("Book(Id=%d, Title=\"%s\")", book.Id, book.Title))

    return 1
}
```

---

#### `main` function

We initialize new "Book" metatable and make itself its own metatble. We add two methods `Create` and `__tostring` and make "Book" a global.

```
L := lua.NewState()
defer L.Close()
L.OpenLibs()

L.NewMetaTable("Book")
L.PushString("__index")
L.PushValue(-2)
L.SetTable(-3)
L.SetMetaMethod("Create", BookCreate)
L.SetMetaMethod("__tostring", BookToString)
L.SetGlobal("Book")
```

This is what we can do in Lua now:

```
local book = Book.Create('Le Petit Prince')
print(book)
print(book:__tostring())
print(Book.__tostring(book))

--out:
Book(Id=1, Title="Le Petit Prince")
Book(Id=1, Title="Le Petit Prince")
Book(Id=1, Title="Le Petit Prince")
```

I hope someone will find it useful. [Full code here](http://pastebin.com/xDjgXzst).